# jquery file upload not working with bootstrap v4.1.3

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

jquery file upload (https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) not working with the latest boostrap version (4.1.3).

Comment: Could you pls explain what your question is?

Comment: Can you provide error details or explain why the file upload is not working? Please include [mcve] containing file upload element.